# Failover-Clustering feature install suddenly requires a reboot before Get-Cluster will work

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm-extension

I have a previous working terraform setup which creates a Windows VM in Azure and runs a bootstrap script via a custom script extension to install and configure SQL Server. This has been working fine for months, but suddenly (I assume after a specific Windows image update) it decides that installing the Failover-Clustering feature now requires a reboot, which breaks the script as there are steps that need to run after this feature is installed, i.e. running the PowerShell Get-Cluster command returns the following error:

`ERROR: Unhandled exception caught: The term 'Get-Cluster' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

If I manually restart the VM and then run the command again, it is now recognised.

So, what I want to know is, is there any way to handle this other than to create an intermediate image with Failover-Clustering installed, and then use that as the base image? I know I can't add a second custom script extension (why Microsoft, just, why?) and I'm struggling to think of an easier way to do this.

Expected `Install-WindowsFeature Failover-Clustering -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools` not to require a reboot, like it use to.

Comment: A bit hacky, but could you rewrite your script to add all the following steps (i.e. after the reboot) as a Windows Scheduled Task that will run on start up and then disable itself at the end?

Comment: I had thought of that, but then there is no way of knowing if the bootstrap completed successfully. I just can't fathom why MS decided we can only have one custom script extension per VM.

Comment: Yeah you'd have to add in additional logging, like piping everything to a log analytics workspace or creating a local log file you'd need to go and check afterwards. Not ideal.

I don't really understand why either; my only guess is that they don't have any method of ordering or prioritising the sequence of the extensions being actioned, and they're worried multiple custom scripts could conflict with each other? Although saying that, that's on us to worry about, not them.

It's likely some carry over from whatever virtualisation technology they use under the hood

Comment: It's not a particularly difficult problem to solve if you're using scripted provisioning and therefore have complete control over the process, but any solution would need to work with terraform. The thing is, you can already add dependencies between extensions. So the only thing stopping this working is the restriction on having only one custom script extension.

Answer (score 0):

> Expected `Install-WindowsFeature Failover-Clustering -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools` not to require a reboot.

The `Failover-Clustering` feature requires a mandatory reboot after installation on the computer. Unfortunately, this reboot requirement cannot be avoided.

There is one possible workaround is to reboot the VM after completing the installation and run the remaining script with Terraform without manual reboot. The script includes a reboot step after installing the Failover-Clustering feature. You can use the `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` resource in Terraform to add a custom script extension that reboots the VM after the feature is installed.

**Terraform Code**

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "VM-resources1"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
      name                = "vm-network1"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
    
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
      name                 = "internal1"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
      name                = "vm-nic1"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "internal1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
      name                = "vm-public-ip1"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
    }
    
    # Create Network Security Group and rules
    resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "my_terraform_nsg" {
      name                = "vm-nsg1"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      security_rule {
        name                       = "Allow_All"
        priority                   = 101
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "*"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "*"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
      network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.example.id
      network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.my_terraform_nsg.id
    }
    resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
      name                = "cluster-vm"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      size                = "Standard_F2"
      admin_username      = "adminuser"
      admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
      network_interface_ids = [
        azurerm_network_interface.example.id
      ]
    
      os_disk {
        caching              = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
      }
    
      source_image_reference {
        publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
        offer     = "WindowsServer"
        sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
        version   = "latest"
      }
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
      name                 = "CustomScripts"
      virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example.id
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
      type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
      type_handler_version = "1.9"
      settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
       "commandToExecute": "powershell Add-WindowsFeature Failover-Clustering -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools"
        }
    SETTINGS
    }
    
    
    
    resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
      triggers = {
        # Add triggers if necessary
      }
      
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
          pwsh -Command "Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'VM-resources1' -VMName 'cluster-vm' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '/home/venkat/VM/additional_script.ps1'"
        EOT
      }
    }
```

**additional_script.ps1**

```
    shutdown /r
    
    Write-Host 'Waiting for VM to restart...'
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 150
    
    Write-Host 'VM has restarted. Resuming script execution...'
    
    Get-Cluster
```

**Terraform apply**

The code executed the Failover-Clustering feature installation and ran additional commands from the script.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work because there is already a bootstrap script being executed via the custom script extension, and you can only have one custom script extension per VM. What I ended up doing is running the second half of the bootstrap (after the reboot) as a scheduled task. I'll write this up as an answer when I get some time.

Comment: I have added a custom script for installing the failover cluster to test running multiple scripts simultaneously.  since you already have an extension for the bootstrap script, you can include the failover cluster command in the script and execute it without using a custom script extension.

Comment: Apologies. I'm on my phone and didn't see the second script using local-exec. I couldn't use that approach because I wanted to minimise changes to existing implementations as this is a shared module, so I went with the scheduled task instead, only using local-exec to confirm successful completion.